# How can I make an http GET trigger for Google Analytics for Azure's Logic Apps?

Tags: azure, google-analytics, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to retrieve data from Google Analytics using an Azure logic app. Could I use Azure Active Directory to sign onto Google Analytics to retrieve the data? Can I utilize the Google Analytics Reporting API or would I have to make my own custom API? Which would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: I can't verify it (I'm not that far yet), but I think that this might provide most of the guidance. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-setup-goog-idp

Comment: Hi Henry, did you find a sloution to this?

Comment: I'd also like to know how far you got with this as I'm looking to do the same..